# Automatic Email Notifications using jquery php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, notifications

I want to send email notifications on every new upload, new comment, new post etc.

Right now I'm calling a function:

```
 notify($user_id, $submitter_id, $post_id);
```

And `notify()` processes these ids and calls `mail()`, the mail is sent to the 'submitter' and people who've commented earlier. The problem is, the script is taking too long and since i'm sending an AJAX request to this script to save the comments also, the user ends up waiting for `notify()` to complete. it's like a chaining process.

Can anyone suggest me a better way to do this? 
I don't want the Ajax script to wait for:

- Saving the comments
- and sending the emails at the same time.

And also I can't use a cron since I want this to be instant, kind of like FB's.

Comment: What is `notify()` taking so long? Maybe you should check this code first.

Comment: wouldn't `notify()`  take long if say, there are 100s of emails to be sent at one time?

Comment: you should something like queue on database and send those mails on background

Comment: @PrabhakarSiddhant: From your description it seems that `notify()` is called upon every action, hence each call to it should only generate one single mail?

Comment: @paul not really, it's more like `notify($user_id, $comment_id, $post_id)` and then scans people who have commented before this comment and sends a mail to them also.

Comment: Well, that's important information. Include that in your question. Nobody here knows what your `notify()` actually does. Best thing is, as already suggested, to use a cron. You can set up a cron to run every minute which is kind of close enough in my opinion.

Comment: Aight @paul. i'll add that info and thanks for the help guys, as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In FB and so on. it's created like I think you may:

when you need update `notify`, you insert to table `outbounds` some message

```
insert into `outbounds` (`email`, `status`, `subject`, `message`, `created`, `sent`)
value ('some@address.net', STATUS::created, 'Some thing is happened', 'Message here', NOW(), NULL);
```

And script which is always running, or execute like by `cron`, or, you can curl this script with set  up timeout=1 for send messages

```
select * from `outbounds` where status = STATUS::created
```

Don't forget after successfuly sent

```
update `outbounds` set `status` = STATUS::sent, sent = NOW() where id = $message_id
```

Comment: would you guys say, **cron** is the best option for me? i wanted to avoid a scheduler/cron and make it more instant. can't i mix jquery and php to make both the things asynchronously active? 
And if i user this:
*would i have to keep the cron runnning all the time 
and if i set it to every 30Secs, will it not make the server burdened?

Comment: All mail delivery is asynchronous. If you dont like use cron - use constantly running script like FB. And, I'd read comments - may be your DB is not optimizied? Do U try make faster executer `select * from recepients`?

Comment: Just have a script which is always running, as Sergey suggested above as one of the options. The way I'd do this would be to write a little server, which waits for connections on a port, and then sends out mail from the DB until the queue is empty, and then goes back to sleep. This means it's not busy waiting - which you never want to do, but it reacts immediately when needed. The server doesn't need to be complex.

Comment: understood. Cron seems to be the best option here. thanks @Sergey i'll use this only.

Comment: i think it'll make the answer also complete if we add this; suggest a tutorial for cron jobs(creation). thanks.

Comment: At Linux : http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/running-php-scripts-with-cron/, please use the power, Luke, sorry: please use google for searcg tutorials.

Comment: https://www.interspire.com/support/kb/questions/377/How+do+I+set+up+CRON+on+my+server+using+SSH,+Cpanel+or+Plesk%3F another ref.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sending 100s of email at a time, I'd recommend a third party service like [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or, my personal favorite [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com).  You should be able to ping those services and continue the remainder of your functions without waiting for a callback. Additionally, their latency is low, so your mail would be delivered almost instantaneously.

Comment: [AlphaMail](http://www.comfirm.se) is another alternative, and here is a comparison of even more [transactional emailing providers](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/transactional-emailing-providers-mailjet-sendgrid-critsend).

Answer (score 1):

Use a queue to store e-mails that are due to be sent, and let a script (for example a `cron` job) send out those mails. This way, the user only has to wait for the insertion of the mail in the queue, which may not take long.

There are various pitfalls when sending large quantities of mail though, and `mail()` really isn't the best solution here.